# how to combine repeated rows with missing fields R

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a a dataset with multiple repeated entries, the entries are largely the same, but with data missing, The missing data could be in any field except for the ID. For example:

```
 A tibble: 5 x 4
 ID    name    age   fsm
  <chr> <chr> <dbl> <dbl>
1 0001  Peter    13     NA
2 0001  NA       13     1
3 0002  Jane     13     1
4 0002  Jane     NA     1
5 0003  Billy    12     0
```

I need to combine the rows, i.e. merging the NAs with the given values from other rows that have the same ID

```
 ID    name    age   fsm
  <chr> <chr> <dbl> <dbl>
1 0001  Peter    13     1
2 0002  Jane     13     1
3 0003  Billy    12     0
```

Above data example as a dput:

```
structure(list(ID = c("0001", "0001", "0002", "0002", "0003"), 
name = c("Peter", NA, "Jane", "Jane", "Billy"), age = c(13, 
13, 13, NA, 12), fsm = c(NA, 1, 1, 1, 0)), class = c("spec_tbl_df", 
"tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -5L), spec = structure(list(
cols = list(ID = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character", 
"collector")), name = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character", 
"collector")), age = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
"collector")), fsm = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
"collector"))), default = structure(list(), class = c("collector_guess", 
"collector")), skip = 1L), class = "col_spec"))
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Updated**
Special thanks to dear @akrun who does not hesitate to provide insight to our solutions and share his knowledge and experience with us.

I hope this is what you are looking for:

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  group_by(ID) %>%
  summarise(across(everything(), ~ first(na.omit(.x))))

# A tibble: 3 x 4
  ID    name    age   fsm
  <chr> <chr> <dbl> <dbl>
1 0001  Peter    13     1
2 0002  Jane     13     1
3 0003  Billy    12     0
```

This solution also works. It may sound a bit verbose but quite useful and handy in these kinda situations:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(purrr)

df %>%
  nest(data = -c(ID)) %>%
  mutate(data = map(data, ~ map_dfc(., na.omit))) %>%     # We use one map function inside the other since one will iterate elements of the nested list and the other iterate over the elements of the underlying tibbles
  unnest(cols = c(data)) %>%
  group_by(ID) %>%
  summarise(across(everything(), first))

# A tibble: 3 x 4
  ID    name    age   fsm
  <chr> <chr> <dbl> <dbl>
1 0001  Peter    13     1
2 0002  Jane     13     1
3 0003  Billy    12     0
```

Comment: Here when I applied `na.omit` solely on the grouped data without choosing the first row I realized it had a surprising effect. Instead of removing rows with `NA` values it completes them with the corresponding values of the same group.

Comment: thanks @Anoushiraven I've been away from R for about two years and very pleased to meet the across command for the first time.

Comment: My pleasure. Glad I could help. Yes thanks to `across` a whole host of other functions like `summerise_all`, `summarise_if` and etc have been superseded.

Comment: It is because there may be duplicate non-NA elements.  Wrapping with `first` gets only the first non-NA element (if the other values are the same, then it is fine)

Comment: @akrun I omitted the `first` function but still all rows are there with NA values replaced.

Comment: summarise can return more than one row per group.  So, if you remove the `first`, for ID 001, there is one non-NA element for name and fsm while there are two for age.  that means the one non-NA element can be recycled to match the length of the max column or else you have to wrap it in a `list` which can have different length (a data.frame/tibble needs the length to be same for each column

Comment: Interesting reading, both. My dataset appears to be a little more complex than I was hoping. See this:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67055389/dplyr-function-to-combine-repeated-data-remove-missing-data-and-maintain-confl

Comment: @pluke I checked your most recent post. The problem is this time around `ID` is not unique per person and for example the missing `name` in ID 001 could be either Peter or Barry. I think we need a little bit of judgment call here.

Answer (score 3):

One `data.table` option

```
> setDT(df)[, lapply(.SD, function(...) fcoalesce(as.list(...))), ID]
     ID  name age fsm
1: 0001 Peter  13   1
2: 0002  Jane  13   1
3: 0003 Billy  12   0
```

or

```
> type.convert(setDT(df)[, as.list(do.call(fcoalesce, asplit(.SD, 1))), ID], as.is = TRUE)
   ID  name age fsm
1:  1 Peter  13   1
2:  2  Jane  13   1
3:  3 Billy  12   0
```